# Wilcoxon signed rank test sample size in R

Tags: r, wilcoxon-signed-rank

is there any procedure available to calculate sample size estimate for 2 samples Wilcoxon signed rank test in R?
The sample size library doesn't have this option.

Background:

I am running an online experiment. I get new data everyday: I want to know what is the minimum sample size to stop enabling me to observe significant results.

One option I thought of is to calculate the p-value every day and see when it converges to above or below the 0.05 over time.

Moreover, my dataset contains dispersed observations, meaning more than 90% of the observations value zero - with consequent ties in the test calculations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about minimum sample size? You know the sample size directly from your samples, you don't need Wilcoxon test to give you that.

Comment: Yes, edited my question. @Statistics

Comment: If you're checking for significance each day you're doing sequential testing; the usual significance levels (even if correctly calculated for such a heavy level of ties) will be *wrong*. See [Sequential Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_analysis). Any resulting estimates will be biased